# Semáforos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async, promises, semáforo

Como posso criar semáforos em JavaScript?
Eu tenho um script assíncrono que executa *n* vezes, gostaria de que quando as *n* tarefas terminassem outra tarefa fosse executada. Eu utilizei acesso normal a uma variável mas isso pode causar condição de corrida.
Código promise:

```
var load_thumbs_promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var itens_id = formData.get('items_id');
            itens_id = itens_id.split(",");
            itens_id.forEach(function (item, index) {
                if(formData.get("type_" + item) == 'pdf')
                {
                    var pdf_url = formData.get("pdf_url_" + item);

                    PDFJS.getDocument(pdf_url).promise.then(function (doc) {
                        var page = [];
                        page.push(1);//Get first page

                        return Promise.all(page.map(function (num) {
                            return doc.getPage(num).then(makeThumb)
                                .then(function (canvas) {
                                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                                    formData.append("pdf_thumb_" + item, img);
                                    console.log(index);

                                    if(index == itens_id.length - 1)
                                    {
                                        console.log("d");
                                        resolve("It's done");
                                    }
                                });
                        }));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Na pergunta tens _"gostaria de que quando as n tarefas terminassem outra tarefa fosse executada"_, e isso é o que `Promise.all` faz, e que estás a usar. Qual é a parte que não funciona?

Comment: A ideia é executar uma outra tarefa, também assíncrona, quando todas as tarefas executadas por load_thumbs_promise terminasse.

Comment: Podias usar uma Promise.all onde fazes um map em vez de `itens_id.forEach` e depois `return PDFJS.getDocument...`, acho que seria por aí. Já testaste isso?

Comment: Não sou muito acostumado a utilizar promises, acho que não entendi bem o que você sugeriu mas vou pesquisar. Obrigado.

Comment: Vou dar uma resposta com uma sugestão, como não sei o que esse código faz arrisco alguns bugs, mas acho que vai ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muda esse `forEach` para um `.map` que retorne uma promise, assim tens uma promise por cada `Promise.all`. Depois usas esse `var itemsFetcher = itens_id.map(function(item, index) {` que coloquei no exemplo para saber quando todas as Promises e sub promises tiverem resolvido.

```js
var itens_id = formData.get('items_id');
itens_id = itens_id.split(",");
var itemsFetcher = itens_id.map(function(item, index) {
  if (formData.get("type_" + item) == 'pdf') {
    var pdf_url = formData.get("pdf_url_" + item);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        PDFJS.getDocument(pdf_url).promise.then(function(doc) {
          var page = [];
          page.push(1); //Get first page

          return Promise.all(page.map(function(num) {
            return doc.getPage(num).then(makeThumb)
              .then(function(canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                formData.append("pdf_thumb_" + item, img);
                console.log(index);

                if (index == itens_id.length - 1) {
                  console.log("d");
                  resolve("It's done");
                }
              });
          }));
        });
      }
    });
});

Promise.all(itemsFetcher).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Ajudou bastante, obrigado.